# How to put $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in given code?

Tags: php, server

I want to put `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` here on place of **http://www.themobilesapp.com/holi/holi?name=** in this code.. I'm unable to solve this.

This is my code with css class.

```
<a class="magic" href="whatsapp://send?text=This year Wish Happy Holi to your friends and their family in different way :) . Click on link and receive my Happy Holi Wishes :) Enter your name and send your Wishes.%0AðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ %0Ahttp://www.themobilesapp.com/holi/holi?name=<?= $name; ?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share on Whatsapp
        </a>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? `PHP_SELF` has the filename of the running script which is not necessarily the same as the current URL.

Comment: here I removed .php from holi.php? and now it is holi?

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing to do is:

```
<?php $link = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].str_replace(".php","",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."?name=".$name; ?>
<a class="magic" href="whatsapp://send?text=This year Wish Happy Holi to your friends and their family in different way :) . Click on link and receive my Happy Holi Wishes :) Enter your name and send your Wishes.%0AðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ðŸ‘‡ðŸ¾ %0Ahttp://www.themobilesapp.com/<?= $link ?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share on Whatsapp</a>
```

Note that this assumes that all you're doing is just removing the `.php` extension from the file and the `SERVER_NAME` is configured correctly in your vhost. Any other rewriting will not work.